# Is it possible to return options of a tkinter button?

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to write something along the lines of

```
if button has option bg='red':
    do something
```

Is there a way to return the button's options in this way with tkinter?

Comment: research the `cget` method.

Comment: @BryanOakley does exactly what I wanted, thanks!

Comment: `button.cget('bg') == 'red'` or `button['bg'] == 'red'`